Double Integral of $3y$ over a Region Defined by a Semicircle
I am trying to evaluate the following double integral:
$$ \int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1 - y^2}}^{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} 3y \, dx \, dy $$
Can anyone help me with the solution or provide insights into the process?
I tried changing the order, but I'm not getting the expected answer. If I solve without changing the order, I get the actual answer. Why are these answers inconsistent?
First, I want to understand the change of order of integration for this problem. Here is how I set it up:

The given region is described by $-\sqrt{1 - y^2} \le x \le \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ and $0 \le y \le 1$. This region is a semicircle with radius 1, centered at the origin.

To change the order of integration, we need to re-describe the region in terms of $x$ and $y$.

$-1 \le x \le 1$, since the semicircle's boundary extends from $x = -1$ to $x = 1$.
For each fixed value of $x$, $0 \le y \le \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, which is the upper half of the circle.



Thus, the integral with the order changed becomes:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} 3y \, dy \, dx $$
Can anyone help me continue from here and evaluate this double integral or provide any guidance on the next steps?

If you have an attempt, that should be included as context for prospective answerers to consider.

If we can't see your solution, how can we tell where the error is?

@Semiclassical i edited the qn, please refer it

The integrals are written correctly and they are equal.

i might've made some mistake ig

To help figure out which calculation has an error, the answer is $2$.

changing the order of integration kinda messes up the integral $$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}3y \ dx \ dy$$ can be rewritten as $$\int_0^1  \Big[3xy|_{x=-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{1-y^2}}\Big] \ dy$$ which is $$-3\int_0^1 -2y\sqrt{1-y^2} \ dy$$ sub in $u=1-y^2$, $du=-2y^2dy$ and its pretty easy to get the answer (I got $2$)
Edit: I realized I misunderstood the question. I don't know why you would change the order of integration in the first place since the upper bounds of the inside integral depend on $y$

I agree with aceisfort's answer, but I believe there is a possibility you may be confusing changing the order of integration with changing the coordinate system, assuming that you went over that. It is much easier to solve this problem in polar coordinates.
Note that the region is simply a semicircle of radius $1$ in the first and second quadrants. This is very easy to set up as a double integral. Also note that $y=r\sin(\theta)$.
$$\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} 3y dx dy = \int_0^\pi \int_0^1 3yr dr d\theta = \int_0^\pi \int_0^1 3r^2 \sin (\theta) dr d\theta.$$
This integral is much nicer to work out.
$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 3r^2 \sin (\theta) dr d\theta = \int_0^\pi \left[ r^3 \sin (\theta) \right]_{r=0}^{r=1} d\theta = \int_0^\pi \sin (\theta) d\theta = \left[ -\cos(\theta) \right]_0^\pi = 2.$$
